# How to publish libraries from Ivy cache to artifactory Ivy repos

Tags: ivy, artifactory

We lost our ivy repository for 3rd party libraries (a lot of them). The only thing we have is the ivy cache sitting on a build agent. Now we decide to move to Artifactory, ivy:install can copy dependencies from a repo to another, but ivy cache is not a repo. In addition, the ivy cache keeps all versions of a jar file under the same directory (ivy cache default pattern) - [organization]/[module]/[type]s/ (no revision). But we'd like to sort them out into different directories - [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/.

After doing this, should the new repo in artifactory function the same as any other repository? In other words, do I miss anything by creating a repository in this way?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new [repository layout](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) in Artifactory that will match the Ivy cache layout:

```
[org]/[module]/[type]s/[module](-[classifier])-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).[ext]
```

Then create a new [local repository](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories) configured with the Ivy cache layout and [import](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Importing+and+Exporting#ImportingandExporting-Import) the content of your Ivy cache into the new local repository.
Finally create a new [virtual repository](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories) configured with the default Ivy layout and include the local repository you created. The virtual repository will perform the transformation between the Ivy cache layout and the Ivy default layout. You will need to configure Ivy to resolve artifacts from the virtual repository. In addition you will be able to include other Ivy repositories in this virtual.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JFrog, the documentation says that you can browse to the jar file and import it in the the repository manually.  Once in JFrog you should be able to pull the jars down from it without any problems.  I have not done this personally, only from reading the documention since I wanted to import .m2/repositories into JFrog after the old JFrog was shutdown and the backups lost so we had to import jars that don't exist anymore in maven and get them into the new JFrog.

If you don't want to use .ivy2/cache as your source location, you can use maven to manually ingest a jar can install it into .m2.  This is one of the many web pages that take about how to do it:

[How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project?rq=2)

It talks about making local maven repos (mvn deploy:deploy-file) and install direct (mvn install:install-file).   Use the ivy jars as you -Dfile value and then configure the m2 location using groupId, arifactId, and version like this:

```
mvn install:install-file \
-Dfile=./javax.sip.jain-sip-sdp/jain-sip-sdp-1.2.148.jar \
-DgroupId=javax.sip \
-DartifactId=jain-sip-sdp \
-Dversion=1.2.148 \
-Dpackaging=jar
```

Hopes this helps you.